# Meteor JS: include dynamic name template in layout

Tags: node.js, meteor, pug

I have this basic layout. I want to include a dynamic header to be included in the template. +header should be like this +{{get_header_name}}. get_header_name is a helper function. I tried this idea but jade will throw an error. Any ideas how to make it dynamic?

*basic.jade*

```
template(name="basicLayout")
    #main
        header
            +header // <--- make this a dynamic using helper (get_header_name)
            +search
        else
            +yield
        footer
            +footer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use Iron Router, you can use [Template.dynamic](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic).

Define helper that returns session with template name:

```
Session.set('headerTemplateName', 'defaultHeader');
Template.basicLayout.helpers({
  headerTemplate: function() {
    return Session.get('headerTemplateName');
  }
});
```

Use that helper in your basicLayout template:

```
+Template.dynamic template=headerTemplate
```

Now, when you change value of session headerTemplateName anywhere in the app, your header template will change according to it:

```
Session.set('headerTemplateName', 'anotherHeader');
```

If you use Iron Router, check out Layouts and Regions: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#layouts